# Fix Signup, Login and Logout on the right side of Navbar using Laravel Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to build a Nav Bar, and so far I am unable to make the **Signup**, **Login** and **Logout** buttons appear on the right side(logout appears if a user signs in,and it replaces both Signup and Login,again on the right side). *I tried a few solutions already there in Stackoverflow, but they could not solve my problem*. Also, *the **icons** of Signup and Login do not appear*. I have attached  screenshots, showing what I mean, and codes below to show what I have done so far.

Navbar before login (notice that there is **no icon** for singup and login)

[image: Navbar before login]

Navbar after login
[image: Navbar after login]

**Blade**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

     <!-- CSRF Token Meta Added -->
      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
       <!-- Ajax script -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Sweet Alert -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
   <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-info navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">User Info</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
    
  </ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="new_user"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user fontawesome-lock"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  
  
</nav>
    </div>
   
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, the page **isn't** responsive. What can I do to make it happen?

Comment: Try using div class 'nav justify-content-end' 

    <ul class="nav justify-content-end">

Comment: Nope. No change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed, you can try this out.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-info">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="login">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link"href="new_user">Signup</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

For the **logout** in the navbar, you can replace the **login** and **singup** with **logout** in the code. DOn't forget to check if the user is authenticated. I haven't included that here.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that **you are replicating a nav solution made for Boostrap 3**, and you are using Boostrap 4 on your project, from what I can see in the code.

So, take a look at the documentation for Boostrap 4 Navbar here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/

The issues you have in your code are:

1. You are missing the list item of your element "features"
2. You havent align the content using margins as stated on the documentation
3. Glyphicons is no longer the icon package for Boostrap 4, use FontAwesome instead

And here is your code with some changes to make it work:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand bg-info navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index">User Info</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="new_user"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="login"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Login</a></li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Nope. I made sure, I checked the docs before doing it. By the way, I got the answer. One of my colleagues helped me

Comment: Great, good news. Do you mind sharing the solution, for future reference? :)

Comment: I will ask him to do it